# Database/PHP design- adding a list of other entity instances to another entity instance?

Tags: php, html, mysql

So my question is very much just a database design question. I'm relatively new to PHP, taking my first database course, and I'm trying to figure out how best to execute my idea.

So I'm building a membership database. Within this database there are "members" and there are "meetings," represented as two separate tables. I'm wondering what might be the best way to add a list of members to a meeting instance, or create a relationship table between the two. For example, would you advise that each member ID (primary key) be added individually (say, via a bunch of text input form fields) when creating a new meeting instance? Or perhaps is there a way to easily have the user upload a CSV or excel file of primary key user id numbers and, from those user number ids, easily create a relationship table?

Hope this is clear- just hoping to get some advice/insight, perhaps I'm not aware of the easiest way... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what are you trying to do in your particular case, but is sounds to me that you should have three tables:

1. members - you have that one already
2. meetings - you also have that one already
3. members_meetings: this one is the table, that will join the two tables. And the required fields in that table should be:

   - member_id - the id of particular member, points to the id field in your members table
   - meeting_id - the id of the meeting, this member is attending, points to the id field in the meetings table

Than, if you want to get all members, that are attending meating X, you can just run the following query:

```
SELECT members.* FROM members_meetings LEFT JOIN members ON members_meetings.member_id = members.id WHERE members_meetings.meeting_id=X
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I have at the moment. I'm just wondering what would be the most ideal way to design my html & php, if there is an ideal way. Conceivably, there will be many meetings and many members. Members can attend many meetings and meetings can have any number of attendees. So I'm trying to get help about whether I should perhaps have many html fields for member ids (members who attended a specific meeting) as part of my "insert meeting" option, or if there's a better/more efficient way to do this rather than have the user enter number by number.

Comment: You could perhaps show the user a multiple select box, based on the records from the members table. The select will be with member names, and for values you will use member ids.That way the user will just check which members he wants to add to that meeting

Comment: I considered that, but I'm worried the select drop down might get a bit annoying to have to navigate with 1000+ members. You are right that this is certainly easier for the user than having to enter them all in, though. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The solution is dynamic select box. These select boxes have a search field on top. See here:
https://select2.github.io/examples.html or https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: If you have really big tables with members and you do not want laggy select box, you can also make these dynamic select boxes to load content via ajax based on the searched string. E.g. when the user types for example john, you can fetch members that only contain the word john in their names and add them to the select.

Comment: Ah, okay! Definitely have a better idea of my options now, thank you very much!